# I am not able to install TestNG using eclipse MARS2.0

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng

[This is the error that i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPnTY.png)

In the Java - Eclipse tool, Navigated to "Help" -> "Install New Software" -> and clicked on "Add" button.
"Add Repository" window is displayed and in "Name" field entered as "TestNG" and in location entered as "http://beust.com/eclipse/" and clicked on "OK" button and getting error message as "could not find the url

I have also changed Network Connections from Manual to Direct and Native. Still not working.

Comment: Try http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release//updatesites/6.10.0.201612030230/

Comment: It gives a popup window saying: "No software site found at 
http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release//updatesites/6.10.0.201612030230/"

Answer (score 0):

try.. from marketplace. In Help >> Market Place >> Search for TestNG and install it.

Comment: It shows popup saying:         Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot resolve host
This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Unknown Host: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Unknown Host: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
server.proxy.org
This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
server.proxy.org